# Finding the nonnegative integer exponents that minimize a product

Tags: optimization, integer-programming

I've been trying to solve a problem which seems to be a multiplicative optimization problem:

> Given a threshold $T > 0$, and a set of integers $b_1, b_2,\dots, b_n > 0$, find integer exponents $e_1, e_2, \dots, e_n \geq 0$ such that
>
> $$P := \prod b_i^{e_i}$$
>
> is the smallest integer *in that form* and greater than or equal to
>   $T$.
>
> Another possible optimization criterion is to relax on $P$ but find
>   exponents such that $\sum e_i$ is minimized.

I'd really appreciate some pointers (not necessarily solutions) to help me get started.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: An example of `B` can be `{2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 11, 13, 16}`

Comment: won't it be easier in log domain?

Comment: @Creator Thought about the log domain. Didn't get anywhere :(

Comment: I'm not sure I see the difficulty.  If you assume $T>0$ and $b_i > 1$ for all $i \in \{1, ..., k\}$, and define $P = \lceil T \rceil$, just define $e_i=0$ for $i \in \{2, 3, ..., k\}$ and choose $e_1$ to satisfy $P = b_1^{e_1}$.

Comment: @Michael, for example, if $T = 5$, your approach will yield $8$, but the optimal solution is $ 2 \times 3 = 6$.

Comment: @Michael $b_i$ has to be integer.

Comment: @K.G : For $T=5$ and $\{b_i\} = \{2, 3, ..., 16\}$ we get $P=\lceil T\rceil =5$ and indeed $P=2^{e_1}3^04^0\cdots 16^0$ for $e_1 = \frac{\log(5)}{\log(2)} \approx 2.321928095$.  I do not know what your comment means, the one containing "8" and "$2 \times 3$".  My other comment had a typo where I said $b_1=\log(5)/\log(2)$ instead of $e_1=\log(5)/\log(2)$.  I rewrite the comment here for convenience.  Whether or not $b_i$ is integer does not change the thrust of my comments above.

Comment: @K.G. : I see you have edited the question to add the new assumption that the _exponents_ $e_i$ are also integer.  That significantly changes the problem.

Comment: Are the bases and exponents **nonnegative**?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo The bases are positive, and the exponents are nonnegative.

Comment: @K.G. How many $b$'s do you expect to have? How big is $T$?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo There's ~20 $b$'s, and $T$ is bounded by $2^{32}$.

Answer (score 3):

Note that 
$$
\ln P=\ln(\prod_{i}b_i^{e_i})=\sum_i\ln{b_i^{e_i}}=\sum_ie_i\ln b_i
$$
In other words, $\ln P$ is linear with respect to variables $e_i$, which is good news.

Your problem is thus equivalent to
$$
\min\limits_{e_i\in \mathbb{N}}\;\left\{\sum_{i=1}^n (\ln b_i) e_i\;|\; \sum_{i=1}^n(\ln b_i) e_i\ge \ln{\tau},\; \prod_{i=1}^n b_i^{e_i} \in \mathbb{N}\right\}
$$

As pointed out by Rodrigo de Azevedo, you can omit the last constraint ($\prod_{i=1}^n b_i^{e_i} \in \mathbb{N}$) if $b_i$ and $e_i$ are **positive** integers. Therefore, in this case, your problem is a pure integer linear problem, easy to solve.

So you end up with
$$
\min\limits_{e_i\in \mathbb{N}}\;\left\{\sum_{i=1}^n (\ln b_i) e_i\;|\; \sum_{i=1}^n(\ln b_i) e_i\ge \ln{\tau}\right\}
$$

You can solve this with dynamic programming if $\tau$ is also integer:

Let $$
f_j(t)=\min\limits_{e_i\in \mathbb{N}}\;\left\{\sum_{i=1}^j(\ln b_i) e_i\;|\; \sum_{i=1}^j(\ln b_i) e_i\ge \ln{t}\right\}
$$
Now, either you set $e_{j+1}$ to $0$, and you have $f_{j+1}(t)=f_j(t)$, either you set $e_{j+1}$ to 
$\lambda\in
\left\{ 
1,\cdots,
\left\lceil \frac{\ln t}{\ln b_{j+1}} \right \rceil 
\right\}
\subset \mathbb{N} $, and $f_{j+1}(t)$ equals $\lambda \ln b_{j+1}$, plus the optimal solution for the remaining $j$ variables, with a threshold set to $\ln t-\lambda\ln b_{j+1}=\ln\frac{t}{b_{j+1}^{\lambda}}$. Therefore, the following recursive equations hold:
$$
f_{j+1}(t)=\min\limits_{\lambda\in\left\{ 
1,\cdots,
\left\lceil \frac{\ln t}{\ln b_{j+1}} \right \rceil 
\right\}} \left\{ \lambda \ln b_{j+1}+f_j\left(\frac{t}{b_{j+1}^{\lambda}}\right)\right\}
$$
with
$$
f_1(t)=
\begin{cases}
1 \quad\; \mbox{if}\quad b_1 \ge t\\
\infty \quad \mbox{if} \quad b_1 < t
\end{cases}
$$

Compute $f_n(\tau)$ with this recursion and you are done (it will take $\mathcal{O}(n\ln^2\tau)$ operations).

---

K.G. proposed a quick non-DP implementation to illustrate the idea.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <utility>
#include <cmath>
#include <limits>

using namespace std;

vector<int> base_vec = {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8};
const int base_size = base_vec.size();

pair<vector<int>, int> good_size_recursive (int idx, int t)
{
    pair<vector<int>, int> res;
    res.first = vector<int>(base_size);
    vector<int> ret_exp = vector<int>(base_size);

    if (0 == idx) 
    {
        int lambda = static_cast<int>(ceil(log(t)/log(base_vec[0])));
        ret_exp[0] = lambda;
        int best_bound = static_cast<int>(pow(base_vec[0], lambda));
        res = make_pair(ret_exp, best_bound);
        return res;
    }

    int best_bound = numeric_limits<int>::max();
    //fixed error in lambda calculation
    int lambda = static_cast<int>(ceil(log(t)/log(base_vec[idx])));

    for (int i = 0; i <= lambda; i++)
    {
        pair<vector<int>, int> curr_res;
        curr_res = good_size_recursive(idx - 1, 
            static_cast<int>(ceil(
                (double)t/pow(base_vec[idx], i)
                ))
            );
        int curr_bound = curr_res.second * static_cast<int>(pow(base_vec[idx], i));

        if ((curr_bound < best_bound) && (curr_bound >= t))
        {
            best_bound = curr_bound;
            res = curr_res;
            res.first[idx] = i;
            res.second = curr_res.second * static_cast<int>(pow(base_vec[idx], i));
        }
    }

    return res;
}

int main () {
    int t;
    cout << "Please enter t: ";
    cin >> t;

    pair<vector<int>, int> sol = good_size_recursive(base_size - 1, t);
    cout << "base sizes:" << endl;
    for (auto b : base_vec)
        cout << b << '\t';
    cout << endl << "exponets:" << endl;
    for (auto s : sol.first)
        cout << s << '\t';
    cout << endl << "Result:" << endl;    
    cout << sol.second << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm not very familiar with optimization problems. Can you please elaborate on the formulation of the equivalent problem, especially on the variables $\tau$ and $Z$?

Comment: I think $\tau$ refers to $T$ in the question?

Comment: Forget the $Z$. $\tau$ is your threshold.

Comment: I'm afraid the last constraint $\exp(t) \in N$ cannot be relaxed. How can it be solved in that case?

Comment: You don't really need $t$, I just added it because I think the problem is more clear this way , but of course you can eliminate the variable, it won't change anything.

Comment: What about the last constraint? Doesn't the integrality of the $b_i$'s ensure the integrality of $\exp (t)$?

Comment: The problem is we have $\ln b_i$, which is not necessarily integer. And even if $\ln b_i$ were integer, the exponential of an integer is not necessarily integer either.

Comment: @Kuifje If $t := \ln \prod b_i^{e_i}$ then $\exp(t) = \prod b_i^{e_i}$. If $b_i$ and $e_i$ were positive integers, then integrality would be assured. The problem is that the OP hasn't mentioned they are positive.

Comment: A yes, great point.

Comment: @Kuifje Suppose $n=2$, $b_1 = b_2 = 3$ and $e_1 = e_2 = -1$. Then $b_1^{e_1} b_2^{e_2} = (3^{-1})^2 = \frac 1 9$, which is not an integer.

Comment: Yes you are absolutely right. I agree, positivity of the integers is necessary.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo @ kuifje. The bases are positive, and the exponents are nonnegative. Can you point me to some slides or a book chapter to solve problems of this kind? Thank you.

Comment: In this case, I would suggest the [Branch-and-Bound algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_and_bound). There are free open source solvers that can do this for you. I personally recommend the [PuLP](https://pythonhosted.org/PuLP/) framework.

Comment: @ kuifje, than you so much! I'll implement the algorithm myself :) @RodrigodeAzevedo Do you also agree on the Branch-and-Bound algorithm?

Comment: Good luck with implementing it yourself...don't want to discourage you but that is a lot of work. Send me your data and I'll run the computations if you prefer.

Comment: @ kuifje. Thank you so much for the tips and even offering to run the computations. The $T$'s are [the Sophie Germain primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophie_Germain_prime), or a subset of them. I'll read the wiki page and some slides, and give it a shot ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42060/discussion-between-k-g-and-kuifje).

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo, I think for the $t - \lambda ln (b_{j+1})$ to be correct, $t$ has to be interpreted as the sum rather than the product. Therefore, the optimization condition should be $\sum_{i=1}^j(\ln b_i) e_i\ge t$. What do you think?

Comment: @Kuifje, I finally got some time to implement the algorithm you drafted. I have to say it's erroneous to categorizes it to DP. The assumption of $\tau$ being integer only holds in the first call, in the recursive calls, $t/d_{j+1}^{\lambda}$ may not be integer, since $\tau$ is merely a threshold, instead of a solution in the required form (product of powers). But thank you very much for the inspiration.

Comment: That is a good point. I think in practice the most efficient way to solve this remains Integer Programming with a commercial or open-source solver (such as CBC), if the input is not too large.